# Using react native async storage getItem

Tags: react-native, promise, asyncstorage, reason, bucklescript

```rut
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    ReactNativeAsyncStorage.getItem("jwt")
    |> Js.Promise.then_(jwt => {Js.log(jwt)});
    None;
  });
```

Error:

```
This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         Js.Promise.t('a) = Js.Promise.t('a)
```

I am using https://github.com/reason-react-native/async-storage with https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Answer (score 2):

The type of `Js.Promise.then_` is

```rust
('a => t('b), t('a)) => t('b)
```

which means the function passed to it must return a, and that `then_` itself will return that promise.

You're making two mistakes in your code:

1. You are not returning a promise from the function you pass to `then_`
2. You are not handling the promise returned by `then_`.

The following fixes both:

```rust
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    let _: Js.Promise.t(unit) =
      Js.Prmoise.(
        ReactNativeAsyncStorage.getItem("jwt")
        |> then_(jwt => resolve(Js.log(jwt)))
      );
    None;
  });
```

`let _: Js.Promise.t(unit) = ...` uses the wildcard pattern to discard the result of the following expression. The type of the result is `Js.Result.t(unit)`, which is annotated to protect against accidental partial application.

`resolve(Js.log(jwt))` will return a promise with the result of calling `Js.log`, which is `unit`, hence why the resulting promise has the type `Js.Promise.t(unit)`.

See the [Reason documentation](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/promise) for more on how to use promises.

Comment: Why is getItem wrapped in  a promise again.

Comment: It isn't. `Js.Promise.(...)` just opens the namespace so you don't have to repeatedly qualify its functions. It's the same as `open Js.Promise`, except constrained to a single expression. See https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/module#open-ing-a-module